# How to send multidimensional POST in Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I use requests.api lib to send post request. What I want is to send multidimensional POST data and I always come up short with this code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://someurl.com';

request_data = {}
request_data['someKey'] = 'someData'
request_data['someKeytwo'] = 'someData2'
request_data['requestData'] = {'someKey3': 'someData3'}

login = requests.post(url, data=login_data)
```

On the receiving end i get a POST with "requestData" => "someKey3" instead of "requestData" => ["someKey3" => 'someData3']

How do I send the correct POST?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "multidimensional POST"; requests are always linear. Are you trying to emulate how another specific language/library arranges a request?

Comment: Maybe you should post your whole structure as JSON?

Comment: answered my own question. languages like php contain $_POST data in multidimensional arrays and key=> value pairs. I wanted to receive something like $_POST['requestData']['someKey3'] and get "someData3".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer for my question is:

```
import requests

url = 'http://someurl.com';

request_data = {}
request_data['requestData[someKey3]'] = 'someData3'

login = requests.post(url, data=request_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
import json
login = requests.post(rul, data=json.dumps(login_data))
```

This way you receive a json on the the receiving side.

Comment: I don't need to send json. I need to send a POST key => value multidimensional data.